# What's better way to figure out buffer size in a AudioFrame per a call 'onPlaybackAudioFrameBeforeMixing'

Tags: agora.io, unreal-engine5, agora

I'm using Agora unreal-engine plugin in My UE Project.
I need to use Audio-frame not mixing in a thirdparty stuff.
So I implement IAudioFrameObserver and I receive audio-frame on a onPlaybackAudioFrameBeforeMixing callback.
I have always crash within copying buffer in the AudioFrame passed.
Firsttime, I thought the cause would be about the synchronization problem between threads because get the crash after more times than 10 the callback is successful.
So I guard the thread-safe codes using several methods UE provide.
But The crash is still. the crash point is copy the buffer like below:

```
bool MyAudoFrameObserver::onPlaybackAudioFrameBeforeMixing(
    const char* channelId,
     agora::rtc::uid_t UserId,
     IAudioFrameObserverBase::AudioFrame& audioFrame)
{
size_t bytes = audioFrame.samplesPerSec * audioFrame.bytesPerSample * audioFrame.channels;
char mybuffer[32000];
FMemory::Memcpy(mybuffer, audioFrame.buffer,fmin(32000,bytes)); // here crash point

// send mybuffer to another thread side stuff.

return true;
```

I think deeply over, then I pretty doubt to calculate buffer size.
'AudioFrame' definition comment help say Buffer data size: buffer = samples × channels × bytesPerSample.
I just did follow to that. the result is 32000 constantly.
Now I noticed the 'samples' should be number of sample per call instead of samplesPerSec. (for me 16000).
Actually I see the callback is called per around 0.01ms (not always) in the log.
So, that means I have to check the frame's delta time in that call sequence and get the delta-time * samperate(16000). for instance, samples = 0.01 * 16000 (samplesPerSec) = 160
If not so, other way, I have to store evey frames for 1sec? If so, sure I get it samples but I would not find the number of sample to copy buffer per call.

I'm in a wrong?
What's the correct way to copy buffer per call?
I should can find the precise size of the audio-frame's buffer per call.

Please anyone helps.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I just didn't catch API meaning.
I found out the samples per call is the'samplesPerChannel' parameter.
in my test, the samples is counted 160 per call and works good without crash.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).